# flatbuffers::Table* to buffer_pointer

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Consider this scenario.
I'm creating a struct(`flatbuffers::Table`) using `CreateXXX` generated code. This creates the struct on the FlatBuffer buffer and gives me the offset.
Then I can get the memory block with `GetBufferPointer()` and transfer it.
Reversely, if I get a memory block, I can use `GetXXX` to get my struct(`flatbuffers::Table`) from that.

But after I get this struct, if I need to serialize it again, how can I do it? After the serialization, I should be able to transfer that data and do GetXXX on that data like before.

```cpp
flatbuffers::Parser parser;
parser.Parse(schema.c_str());
parser.SetRootType("license");
parser.Parse(j.c_str());

auto* buf = parser.builder_.GetBufferPointer();
auto li = flatbuffers::GetRoot<license>(buf);

std::cout << "ID: " << li->id()->c_str() << " Rand: " << li->rand()->c_str() << " Secret: " << li->secret()->c_str() << std::endl;

uint8_t* buf2 = ????????????
auto li2 = flatbuffers::GetRoot<license>(buf2);

std::cout << "ID: " << li2->id()->c_str() << " Rand: " << li2->rand()->c_str() << " Secret: " << li2->secret()->c_str() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that you keep the original buffer pointer (and size) around. Then you can "re-serialize" it by just writing out the existing buffer.

There is a function `GetBufferStartFromRootPointer` if you really must use just the root (`li` in your example).

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The requirement is to pass the buf2 to Java through JNI and deserialize li2 at Java side.

Comment: Also I need to know, 
1. Does `GetBufferStartFromRootPointer` serialize the inner Tables as well?
2. How can I get the length of the returned buffer?

Comment: That is not clear from your question. Also that has nothing to do with FlatBuffers, as that is the same for any buffer of bytes. Your question should be tagged: c++ java jni. I am no Java expert, but I think there is a subclass of ByteBuffer that will allow you to memory map memory owned by C++.

`GetBufferStartFromRootPointer` doesn't serialize anything, it is simply a way to find the start of the buffer from the root pointer, i.e. the opposite of `GetRoot` (which doesn't (de-)serialize anything either).